# Get coupon data from WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

I have created in WooCommerce two custom coupon types:

```
function custom_discount_type( $discount_types ) {
    $discount_types['cash_back_fixed'] =__( 'Cash Back fixed discount', 'woocommerce' );
     $discount_types['cash_back_percentage'] =__( 'Cash Back Percentage discount', 'woocommerce' );
         return $discount_types;

     }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_discount_types', 'custom_discount_type',10, 1);
```

I would like to get the discount type after Order status is "completed", something like :

```
function wc_m_move_order_money_to_user( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){

    if( $order->get_used_coupons() ) {
        if ($coupon->type == 'cash_back_fixed'){ 
           $coupons_amont =  ???
           ....

       }
    }
}
```

But `$coupon->type` doesn't work.

How can I get the coupon types used in the order?
And how can I get the original coupon amount?.

Thanks

Comment: How can find the coupon amount ( not coupon amounts used in the order)

Comment: Thanks for support me. And now deleted duplicated questions.

Answer (score 44):

**Update 3**

Since WooCommerce 3.7, you should now use the `WC_Abstract` method [`get_coupon_codes()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L822-L838) on the `WC_Order` instance object to get the used coupons from an order, as `get_used_coupons()` method **is deprecated**.

So you will replace in the code:

```
foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon_code ){
```

by:

```
foreach( $order->get_coupon_codes() as $coupon_code ){
```

Then you can get coupon details like:

```
foreach( $order->get_coupon_codes() as $coupon_code ) {
    // Get the WC_Coupon object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);

    $discount_type = $coupon->get_discount_type(); // Get coupon discount type
    $coupon_amount = $coupon->get_amount(); // Get coupon amount
}
```

---

**Update 2**

First you can't access anymore WC objects properties since WooCommerce 3.

> **You should now use [`WC_Coupon` getter methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html) to get coupon details** from the `WC_Coupon` Object instance…

In your case you have to use [**`get_discount_type()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html#_get_discount_type) method or [**`is_type( 'cash_back_fixed' )`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html#_is_type) method …

Here is the way to do it:

```
// Get an instance of WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Coupons used in the order LOOP (as they can be multiple)
foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon_code ){

    // Retrieving the coupon ID
    $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_code, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
    $coupon_id       = $coupon_post_obj->ID;

    // Get an instance of WC_Coupon object in an array(necessary to use WC_Coupon methods)
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);

    // Now you can get type in your condition
    if ( $coupon->get_discount_type() == 'cash_back_percentage' ){
        // Get the coupon object amount
        $coupon_amount1 = $coupon->get_amount();
    }

    // Or use this other conditional method for coupon type
    if( $coupon->is_type( 'cash_back_fixed' ) ){
        // Get the coupon object amount
        $coupon_amount2 = $coupon->get_amount();
    }
}
```

---

To get the coupons discount amounts (and to use also coupons types methods) here is the way:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// GET THE ORDER COUPON ITEMS
$order_items = $order->get_items('coupon');

// print_r($order_items); // For testing

// LOOP THROUGH ORDER COUPON ITEMS
foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ){

    // Retrieving the coupon ID reference
    $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title( $item->get_name(), OBJECT, 'shop_coupon' );
    $coupon_id = $coupon_post_obj->ID;

    // Get an instance of WC_Coupon object (necessary to use WC_Coupon methods)
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);

    ## Filtering with your coupon custom types
    if( $coupon->is_type( 'cash_back_fixed' ) || $coupon->is_type( 'cash_back_percentage' ) ){

        // Get the Coupon discount amounts in the order
        $order_discount_amount = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'discount_amount', true );
        $order_discount_tax_amount = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'discount_amount_tax', true );

        ## Or get the coupon amount object
        $coupons_amount = $coupons->get_amount();
    }
}
```

---

> So to get the **coupon price**, we use the **`WC_Coupon`** **`get_amount()`** method

Comment: This is great! How do we get this information from the cart/session instead of the order?

Comment: something is wrong with your flow. If the type is percantage, `get_amount()` gives the percentage amount. You need to calculate the discount amount per coupon manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to change new orders to "pre-order" (custom status already added in system) if specific coupon used and order paid (so, if processing status engaged).

```
function change_status_to_preorder($order_id) {
    
    $order          = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $coupon_codes   = $order->get_coupon_codes();
    
    if(in_array('MYCOUPON', $coupon_codes) && $order->get_status() == 'processing') {
        $order->update_status('wc-pre-order', 'AUTO: note to shop manager');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'change_status_to_preorder', 1, 1);
```