# Display used coupons on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

Below code for a print coupon on order page

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 20 );
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            
            $reordered_columns['Coupons'] = __( 'Coupons','theme_domain');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}
```

How I can print the current value of coupon for each user order??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following to display used coupon codes in admin order list custom column:

```
// Additional custom column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 20 );
function custom_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    $reordered_columns = array();

    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            $reordered_columns['coupons'] = __( 'Coupons', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Custom column content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_shop_order_column_used_coupons' );
function custom_shop_order_column_used_coupons( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ( ! is_a( $the_order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }

    if ( 'coupons' === $column ) {
        $coupon_codes = $the_order->get_coupon_codes();
        
        if ( ! empty($coupon_codes) ) {
            echo implode(', ', $coupon_codes);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Related: [Get coupon data from WooCommerce orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977174/get-coupon-data-from-woocommerce-orders/44982015#44982015)