# Display used coupons description on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

i want to display used coupons on WooCommerce admin orders list with the coupon description. So i'm using [Display used coupons on WooCommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520971/11987538) answer code and the used coupon code is shown, but can't include the used coupon description.

How is that possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can coupon object by `WC_Coupon` class and use `$coupon->get_description()` to get coupon description. try the below code.

```
function woo_customer_order_coupon_column_for_orders( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $column_key => $column_label ) {
        if ( 'order_total' === $column_key ) {
            $new_columns['order_coupons'] = __('coupons', 'woocommerce');
        }
        $new_columns[$column_key] = $column_label;
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woo_customer_order_coupon_column_for_orders' );
        
function woo_display_customer_order_coupon_in_column_for_orders( $column ) {
    global $the_order;
    if( $column  == 'order_coupons' ) {
        if( $coupons = $the_order->get_used_coupons() ) {   
            foreach( $coupons as $coupon_code ){
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
                if( $coupon ){
                    echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$coupon->code."</b></span>";
                    echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$coupon->get_description()."</p>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '<small><em>'. __('No Coupon') . '</em></small>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'woo_display_customer_order_coupon_in_column_for_orders' );
```

**Tested and works**

[image][image]